# Installing a Python package using Poetry with trusted host and custom URL which contains the .whl files

Tags: python, package, python-poetry

I'm trying to upgrade an older project to use Poetry instead of `requirements.txt`

In the old requirements, there was this dependency:

```
--trusted-host download.pytorch.org
-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch_stable.html


torchvision==0.11.2
torch==1.10.1+cu113
```

I'm not sure how to install this using poetry, I tried:

1. Installing a specific wheel by copying the URL `poetry add https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113/torch-1.10.1%2Bcu113-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl`

   This could cause issues if different Python versions, OS or architecture would be used
2. I was investigating Poetry's documentation here: https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories, it seems I can add more repositories but I'm not sure if this fits the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option to install torch with poetry is indeed to do `poetry add <download_url>`. You can find a matching version and system of the library here: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/.

This indeed can be problematic if you try to run it on different systems or python versions. One option to prevent it is to enforce the python version in the `pyproject.toml`. To run on python3.8 for instance you add this:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
```

Then you can also activate python3.8 virtual env with this command:

```
poetry env use python3.8
```